# spring-kafka starting another container with @RefreshScope annotation

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-kafka, spring-autoconfiguration

I am integrating my spring-kafka consumer with spring-cloud. Here is the bean that basically has the `@KafkaListener`

```
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    @RefreshScope
    SinkGenericKafkaConsumer<String, MessageEvent, MessageEntity> sinkGenericKafkaConsumer(final ContainerConfigProperties containerConfigProperties,
                                                                                           DataSource dataSource,
                                                                                           final SinkKafkaConsumerProperties<MessageEvent, MessageEntity> kafkaConsumerProperties) {
        return new SinkGenericKafkaConsumer<>(containerConfigProperties, kafkaConsumerProperties, dataSource);
    }
```

So when I make a config change and context gets refreshed I was hoping that since I am using `@RefreshScope` when beans are refreshed spring-kafka framework will use the new bean that gets created, but it spawns the new bean as a new container so now I have 2 containers which is not the desired thing. May be I am doing something wrong but can't figure out. Also the datasource i am injecting is not getting refreshed even though it has `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated.

Comment: Why should the datasource be refreshed? Unless that is also annotated with `@RefreshScope`. The consumer will create a new instance of the bean because that is what refresh-scope does. It will do the destruction callbacks so if your `SinkGenericKafkaConsumer` implements `DisposableBean` it should receive the callback and execute the cleanups.

Comment: According to spring doc and class that is annotated with ```@ ConfigurationProperties``` will be created again if the context gets refreshed. That is how my custom bean is getting refreshed as well

Comment: That bean is just a singleton and won't get refreshed without `@RefreshScope`.

Comment: @Denium thats not true the custom bean that I have is not annotated with ```@RefreshScope``` but gets refreshed

Comment: There is clearly an `@RefreshScope` on the code you posted. However a `DataSource` isn't an `@ConfigurationProperties` that will only work for beans that are actually only property holding beans, putting that on an `@Bean` annotation method will only do the binding after the bean has been created. There is a difference between a class level `@ConfigurationProperties` and method level `@ConfigurationProperties`. I nowhere see the documentation you mention by the way, and when updating a configuration it doesn't refresh the whole context, it refreshed/recreates the beans with `@RefreshScope`.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration.java Unfortunately I can't find spring documentation that says beans annotated with ```@ConfigurationProperties``` will refresh automatically. But yeah I have a custom bean(not in the code block in the question) that is annotated with ```@ConfigurationProperties``` and it gets refreshed automatically. Also there are few people who have also writen this in their blog but i cant find official document

Comment: Well if you refresh the context everything will get a new instance, but the `@RefreshScope` works differently. But it is worth investigation (something else to add to my list to write about :)) ).